# Remove item from List and get the item simultaneously

Tags: c#, list

In C# I am trying to get an item from a list at a random index. When it has been retrieved I want it to be removed so that it can't be selected anymore. It seems as if I need a lot of operations to do this, isn't there a function where I can simply extract an item from the list? the RemoveAt(index) function is void. I would like one with a  return value.

What I am doing:

```
List<int> numLst = new List<int>();
numLst.Add(1);
numLst.Add(2);

do
{
  int index = rand.Next(numLst.Count);
  int extracted = numLst[index]; 
  // do something with extracted value...
  numLst.removeAt(index);
}
while(numLst.Count > 0);
```

What I would like to do:

```
List<int> numLst = new List<int>();
numLst.Add(1);
numLst.Add(2);

do
{
  int extracted = numLst.removeAndGetItem(rand.Next(numLst.Count)); 
  // do something with this value...
}
while(numLst.Count > 0);
```

Does such a "removeAndGetItem" function exist?

Comment: You'd have to write your own - as far as I'm aware, only a Stack or a Queue has this sort of functionality built-in. Would this need to be thread-safe?

Comment: Why not get what you want to a new variable/list?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, as it's a breach of pure function etiquette, where a method either has a side effect, or returns a useful value (i.e. not just indicating an error state) - never both.

If you want the function to appear atomic, you can acquire a lock on the list, which will stop other threads from accessing the list while you are modifying it, provided they also use `lock`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T RemoveAndGet<T>(this IList<T> list, int index)
    {
        lock(list)
        {
            T value = list[index];
            list.RemoveAt(index);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind the lock will only help if RemoveAndGet is called simultaneously. Some other function can still modify the list, and you would still have OutOfBoundsException. As mentioned below, exception handling could be considered.

Comment: the first part about commands and queries is just not true, `Add` has side effects and return a value on the very same class here... it's also not always practical, take a Stack for example, `Pop` has side effects and returns a value. that would be strange to keep those two separated.. (I do like the idea of commands and queries, but that concept is not enforced in .NET and not always what you want)

Comment: Personally, I think the "useful" part of my answer still applies to the returned value from `Add`, in the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: The lock() in this answer is irrelevant and misleading.  Any other thread can modify that list.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
  public static T RemoveAndGetItem<T>(this IList<T> list, int iIndexToRemove}
  {
    var item = list[iIndexToRemove];
    list.RemoveAt(iIndexToRemove);
    return item;
  } 
}
```

These are called [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), call as `new List<T>().RemoveAndGetItem(0)`.

**Things to consider in the extension method**

Exception handling with the index that you pass, check that the index is withing 0 and the count of the list before doing this.

Comment: +1 I guess this is the same as the other answer with the lock. Thanks for the exception handling note.

Comment: @Eirik There's no specification regarding what should happen if you pass an invalid index to a method on IList, so I think it's better to leave argument validation to the list implementation.

For all you know, a custom IList implementation might be **expecting** out of range indexes for whatever reason.

Comment: @RichardLovely this is the exact reason why I said it's `something to consider`. Also, what possiblity could a custom list be expecting an index which is out of range, out of curiosity?

Comment: @LukeHennerley A list that appears to wrap cyclically, for instance?  Who are we to assume all programmers are sane - or that what appears madness isn't just really deep genius?